# getting an error while acessing google calendar API. Null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, google-calendar-api

I get a error message below .. when I run the code for hitting google Calendar API.There is a client_secrets.json file that has the credentials (client ID and redirectID) . I unzipped and ran the package google gave, it successfully runs and I could see that by a "Success,Add code here"message. after which it throws me a nullpointer exception for which I'm not sure what has gone wrong.please help. Downloaded the sample project from here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3

```
   May 01, 2014 12:59:42 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Aishwarya Anand\.store\calendar_sample
May 01, 2014 12:59:42 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Aishwarya Anand\.store\calendar_sample
Success! Now add code here.
inserting event ...
Aish Event from the new Google API
2014-05-01T16:59:42.545Z
2014-05-01T17:59:42.545Z
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.cmdline.CalendarSample.insertEventTest(CalendarSample.java:170)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.cmdline.CalendarSample.main(CalendarSample.java:116)
```

Class here,

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.cmdline;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
public class CalendarSample {
    /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Caritas-CalendarAPI/1.0";

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/calendar_sample");
/**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private static Calendar client;
/** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(CalendarSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));

    // Set up authorization code flow.
    // Ask for only the permissions you need. Asking for more permissions will
    // reduce the number of users who finish the process for giving you access
    // to their accounts. It will also increase the amount of effort you will
    // have to spend explaining to users what you are doing with their data.
    // Here we are listing all of the available scopes. You should remove scopes
    // that you are not actually using.
    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
    scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes)
        .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // initialize the transport
      httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

      // initialize the data store factory
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

      // authorization
      Credential credential = authorize();

      // set up global Calendar instance
      client = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

      System.out.println("Success! Now add code here.");
      insertEventTest();

      //getEventList();
     //getEventTest();
      //sertEventTest();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
  }

  private static void getEventList() throws IOException {
      String pageToken = null;
      do {
        Events events = client.events().list("primary").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        for (Event event : items) {
          System.out.println(" id: " + event.getId() + "; summary: " + event.getSummary());
        }
        pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
      } while (pageToken != null);
  }

  private static void getEventTest() throws IOException {

      String eventId = "idkoi3c55lvegs2ev333u28grk5c";
      Event event = client.events().get("primary", eventId).execute();

      System.out.println(event.getSummary());     
  }

  private static void insertEventTest() throws IOException {

      System.out.println("inserting event ...");

      Event event = new Event();

      event.setSummary("Aish Event from the new Google API");
      event.setLocation("Somewhere");

     System.out.println(event.getSummary());

      Date startDate = new Date();
      Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
      DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
      System.out.println(start.toStringRfc3339());
      DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
      System.out.println(end.toStringRfc3339());

      Event createdEvent = client.events().insert("primary", event).execute();


      System.out.println("event id" + createdEvent.getId());
  } 



 }
```

Comment: did  you get to work?  I this this is bug with Google APIs i got the same error for [this example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/quickstart-java) is not working